# JavaScript doesn't see a backgroundColor?

Tags: javascript

Why I can't see my style?

```
    <style>
        .style{
            background-color: pink;
            top: 50px;
            left: 50px;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        window.onload = function () {
            console.log(document.querySelector('.style').style.backgroundColor);
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body><div class="style">A</div></body>
```

Seams that JS can't see a  block with styles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not how `element.style` works. `el.style` only takes from the element's style attribute, so it would only see `backgroundColor` if it had a `style="background-color: red"`.

You want [`window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle):

```
var el = document.querySelector('.style');
var bg = getComputedStyle(el).backgroundColor;
```

You can try on this page, in the console:

```
getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('pre')).backgroundColor
```

Speed:

```
el = document.querySelector('pre');
console.time('getComputedStyle');
for (i=0; i<1000; i++) c = getComputedStyle(el).backgroundColor;
console.timeEnd('getComputedStyle');
```

returns:

```
getComputedStyle: 9.120ms
```

1 frame at 60 fps is 16 ms, so you can do ~ 2000 `getComputedStyle`s per frame.

Comment: But getComputedStyle is a heavy operation. And some people say that it is better to don't use it.

Comment: 'Heavy' as in .03 ms per call, sure. (I'm guessing.) You can do a lot of those in a frame though. It's all relative. Don't compare it to `.style` access. Try it in a few browsers.